# If $A$ can be written as a sum of nilpotent matrices why $trcA=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$. If $A$ can be written as a sum of two nilpotent matrices, why $trcA=0$?

Answer (score 5):

Any nilpotent matrix has a trace equal to zero, just look for it characteristic polynomial. And as the trace is linear, any sum of nilpotent matrices has a zero trace.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of matrices with trace zero has trace zero.  So you must just show that a nilpotent matrix has trace zero.  Suppose $A$ is nilpotent; then the characteristc polynomal is $c_A(x) = x^n$.  But $c_A(x) = x^n + \text{tr}(a)x^{n-1} + $ (more terms of lower order).  Hence $\text{tr}(A) = 0$